# block IP or spam or another problem

Tags: postfix, smtp, mail-transport-agent

I setup an SMTP server(Postfix), Then I send an email to my gmail, I get the following email from gmail:

```
This is the mail system at host mail.pahlevanzadeh.net.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<m.pahlevanzadeh@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.31.27]
    said: 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication information or
    fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best protect our users
    from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. m13si7030284qvk.215 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
    command)


Reporting-MTA: dns; mail.pahlevanzadeh.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 96B203C01C0
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; mohsen@pahlevanzadeh.net
Arrival-Date: Sat,  6 Jun 2020 11:37:33 -0400 (AST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; m.pahlevanzadeh@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;m.pahlevanzadeh@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.26
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication
    information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best
    protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. m13si7030284qvk.215 - gsmtp


salamkdsdjfi.eml
Subject: 
salamkdsdjfi
From: 
Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh <mohsen@pahlevanzadeh.net>
Date: 
6/6/20, 8:06 PM
To: 
Pahlevanzadeh <m.pahlevanzadeh@gmail.com>

dwjkdjkdjvkdlvnfklvnfklvf
```

Where's my problem?

Comment: Did you try going to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

> **host** gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.31.27] **said:** 550-5.7.26 This
>   **message does not have authentication information or fails to**
>   550-5.7.26 **pass authentication checks**.

(emphasis mine)

There isn't a lot more to add to that, Google will not let you send a message to their server from a user of theirs unless you authenticate your SMTP session first.

Comment: I authenticate via `AUTH PLAIN my_base64_string`